# Using redis "pubsub" command in node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

Stack:
Nodes.js: v4.5.0, 
Redis: 3.2.100, 
Node-redis: 2.6.2 (http://redis.js.org)

I was trying to use the "pubsub" command to find the number of subscriptions for a channel.
http://redis.io/commands/pubsub

```
PUBSUB <subcommand> ... args ...
```

Could not find the "pubsub" command available in the node-redis API.
Please help me get the number of redis subscriptions for a channel in node.js environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do.

```
  client.pubsub('NUMSUB', 'news', function(err,result){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(result)
  })
```

Comment: thanks! bitten by the typescript definition not having the pubsub method defined.

Comment: also works:
`client.send_command('PUBSUB', ['NUMSUB', 'news'], function(err,result){...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [redis-messaging-manager](https://github.com/tomyitav/redis-messaging-manager) library for easy Pub-Sub setup.

Creating a pubsub instance:

```
import {PubsubManager} from 'redis-messaging-manager';

let messenger = new PubsubManager({
  host: 'localhost'
});

export default messenger;
```

To publish on a channel:

```
import messenger from '../messenger';

messenger.publish('channel', 'message content');
```

And subscribe on the same channel:

```
import messenger from "../messenger";

console.log('consuming messages..!');
messenger.consume('channel')
    .subscribe(msg => {
        console.log('Got message- ', msg);
    });
```